# Understanding the universal covering of certain surfaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

In a lecture of Algebraic Topology we were given a few examples of universal covering. One of them was the universal covering of connected surfaces with no boundary, saying that its universal covering was the plane (except for the sphere an real proyective plane, which is the sphere).

I don't understand where that comes from, even after asking my professor. Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: What, to you, is a surface? There are two different approaches to answering this question and I'm not sure which you actually want. 1) Cite the classification of surfaces. The only simply connected ones are $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $S^2$ and so only need to argue that $S^2$ only covers $S^2$ and $\mathbb{RP}^2$, hence every other surface is universally covered by $\mathbb{R}^2$. 2) If you have an explicit model of a genus $g$ surface (e.g. as connected sum of $g$ tori, certain quotient of a $4g$-gon), it is possible to explicitly construct a universal cover.

Comment: I would like to understand the different types of surfaces a 2-manifolds. If we consider a connected surface with no borders, is it always compact? If so, then we can use the theorem of classification of compact surfaces and check just a few cases. But I'm not sure if there exists non-compact connected surfaces with no boundary.

Comment: An open disk is certainly non-compact and doesn't have boundary, so no. The claim is true for non-compact surfaces too, but that case is a lot more annoying. Since this is about understanding some examples, I would advise you to only worry about compact surfaces.

Comment: Even so, how can I prove that $\Bbb R^2$ is the universal covering of any non-compact connected surface with no border?

Comment: The universal covering of a non-compact, connected, boundaryless surface is a simply connected, non-compact, connected, boundaryless surface and $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the only such surface. This is a non-trivial result from the classification theory of surfaces.

Comment: Is there any article or book where I can find this information?

Comment: You can take a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3904539/422019). It certainly follows from the complete classification of non-compact, boundaryless surfaces, which is in [this paper by Ian Richards](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1963-106-02/S0002-9947-1963-0143186-0/S0002-9947-1963-0143186-0.pdf). If you're analytically minded, it is also a consequence of the [Uniformization Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem).